# Desenvolvimento de jogos - OpenGl, Directx

Tags: api, opengl, directx

Estou começando a estudar APIs para desenvolvimento gráfico e estou com uma dúvida pertinente. Quando jogos são desenvolvidos, necessariamente são utilizadas APIs. Minha dúvida é em relação ao desenvolvimento do mesmo jogo com APIs diferentes, com finalidade de aumentar a compatibilidade do jogo. Os jogos são desenvolvidos novamente com outra API ou é possível "converter" de uma API para outra?

Comment: *Os jogos são desenvolvidos novamente com outra API?* - Muitas vezes sim, a menos que haja uma terceira API que já faça o trabalho de mapear para uma ou para outra. *É possível "converter" de uma API para outra?* - Sim, mas isso normalmente tem que ser feito manualmente por um programador, exceto se já houver uma terceira API pronta para fazer a conversão/adaptação entre uma e outra.

Comment: Se você está começando considere o Unity: http://unity3d.com/pt ele promete rodar o jogo em várias plataformas, nunca testei isso apenas desenvolvi alguns games nele. A linguagem de programação é C# ou JavaScript.